# PGP Encryption Explanation

Tags: encryption, public-key-encryption, pgp

I know that there are so many resources out there trying to explain the process of PGP encryption, but I'm an idiot and I just can not for the life of me grasp how this works. Where I'm losing it is with all the keys, so I'll try to explain what I think it is and if you can please explain what I'm missing?

So, there is a sender and receiver. The sender generates a session key that's typically a symmetric key. They use the session key to encrypt the message, and then the sender encrypts the session key and the message with the receiver's public key? And the receiver gets the message and decrypts it with their private key (is this also the public key used to encrypt the message?) and then they use the session key inside to decrypt the message?

That felt dumb to even type out, I think I just need an actually decent example that outlines the whole process. If you could find a way to explain it to me like I'm five without leaving out any details that would be amazing

Comment: I think many people feel like idiots trying to understand & use PGP — and that's a big reason for its historic unpopularity, despite its Privacy being Pretty Good.

Comment: You've got the basic gist of hybrid cryptography, yes. Generally we'd use RSA keys nowadays (unless you need post-quantum cryptography, in which case PGP is not an option). RSA is asymmetric encryption, which means that the public and private key are different but belong to the same pair. PGP uses a different method than the hierarchical X.509 (certs in your web browser) for it's trust, it uses a web of trust. By the way, this would be more on topic on [crypto.se], but be sure to check for dupes - I don't have the time for that now.